# awk command not working

Tags: unix, awk, cygwin

My code gives me an error at line 3 with message:

``` syntax error near unexpected token ``ARRAY1=$(awk 'FNR == 1{print $2}' $file) ```

```
set -vx
for file in ls bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt
ARRAY1=$(awk 'FNR == 1{print $2}' $file) # stores the value
let ARRAY1=$ARRAY1/100+1
echo $ARRAY1
value1=$(awk 'FNR == '$ARRAY1'{print $1}' bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/list_for_635_fasta.list) # GETS THE VALUES FROM THE LIST
echo $value1
value2=$(awk 'FNR == 1{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' bwa-0.5.9/bwa-0.5.9/GENOMES/${file:0:13})    # GETS THE VALUES FROM THE LIST
echo $value2
done
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could point out the mistake. It seems to make sense, but I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: You might want to change `for file in ls bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt` to `for file in bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt`

Comment: I did, still an error on the same line.

Comment: You also need a `;do` following the `for` statement.

Comment: ah that was it. that was silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set -vx
for file in bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt; do
  ARRAY1=$( awk 'FNR == 1 { print $2 }' "$file" ) 
  let ARRAY1=$ARRAY1/100+1
  echo "$ARRAY1"
  value1=$( awk -v a1="$ARRAY1" 'FNR == a1 { print $1 }' bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/list_for_635_fasta.list ) 
  echo "$value1"
  value2=$( awk 'FNR == 1 { print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }' bwa-0.5.9/bwa-0.5.9/GENOMES/"${file:0:13}" )  
  echo "$value2"
done
```

If you tell us what shell you're using, we could improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in ls bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt
```

above line should be

```
for file in `ls bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt`
do
```

Comment: actually it can be `for file in bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/Hits_635_25bp/*.txt` ...